# Different step size for different FMUs

Tags: python, simulation, modelica, pyfmi

I have 3 FMUs that I want to simulate with the pyFMI `Master`. The two of them work with a resolution of seconds, but the third with a resolution of hours. Specifically, if I want to simulate for one day, namely 86400 seconds with a step size of 15 minutes, namely 15*60 seconds the FMU with the hour resolution cannot be simulated properly. Is there a way to define different step size for the third FMU?